# Lighttpd proxy path names?

Tags: proxy, lighttpd

I'm trying to configure lighttpd to proxy traffic to one relative path to one proxy server, and traffic to another path to another proxy server.

For example:

```
http://mydomain.com/ proxies to 123.111.111.1
http://mydomain.com/apathname/ proxies to 123.111.111.2
```

I am flumoxed trying to figure out how to the the /apathname/ configured. This is a sample of what I have configured so far, which just directs all traffic to 123.111.111.1

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "mydomain.com" {

    proxy.balance = "fair"

    proxy.server = ( 
        "" =>
            (
                ("host" => "123.111.111.1", "port" => "80" )
            ),

        "apathname" =>
            (
                ( "host" => "123.111.111.2", "port" => "80" )
            )
    )

}
```

My apologies if this question should be on another SO site. I'm primarily a coder, not a network guy, and I know I always get the best answers on SO itself, which is why I'm asking here.

Comment: Have you tried changing the order?. apathname before followed by "" ? and make that "/apathname"

Comment: Thanks Zim. I had to switch the order, and then I recalled that one of the servers was running locally on a different port, but I was specifying the IP and the firewall blocks the port externally. Had to switch that back to 127.0.0.1 and it started working.

Comment: I think this question is better asked on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @Martin Tajur: Couldn't you also configure proxy.server = ( "^/upload(.*)$" => (("host" => "10.2.2.1", "port" => 3000)), "^/submit(.*)$" => (("host" => "10.2.2.2", "port" => 3000)) ) ...especially if one has lots of proxy entries? What are the strength and weaknesses of either approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check the request URL from `$HTTP["url"]` and set up multiple proxy rules, like this:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "(www.example.com)" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/www.example.com"

    $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/upload(.*)$" {
        proxy.server  = ("" => (
            ("host" => "10.2.2.1", "port" => 3000)
        ))
    }

    $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/submit(.*)$" {
        proxy.server  = ("" => (
            ("host" => "10.2.2.2", "port" => 3000)
        ))
    }
}
```

In this example above:

- everything requested from `/upload` will be proxied to `10.2.2.1:3000`.
- everything requested from `/submit` will be proxied to `10.2.2.2:3000`.